# No se guarda la var en js

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código en js, el cual, no me guarda la información del input en la variable. A la hora de activar la funcion mostrar() me devuelve que la variable x no está definida

```js
function crear(){
 var x = document.getElementById("name").value;
 }
function mostrar(){
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name">

<button onclick="crear()">Crear</button>
<button onclick="mostrar()">Mostrar</button>
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
```

Comment: No te puedes quejar 5 respuestas y todas buenas... Efectividad del foro XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenés un problema de englobamiento de la variable, en el `crear()` estás declarando la variable ahí, entonces sólo puede ser visible dentro de esa función.

La solución es declarar la variable fuera de la función.

```js
var x;

function crear(){
 x = document.getElementById("name").value;
}
function mostrar(){
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name">

<button onclick="crear()">Crear</button>
<button onclick="mostrar()">Mostrar</button>
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
```

Answer (score 4):

Es por el ámbito de la variable. El ámbito es donde existe la variable. En este caso Solo existe dentro de la función. Para poder hacer lo que pretendes necesitas una variable global.

```js
var x = ''; //variable global

function crear(){
  var l = ''; // variable local.
 x = document.getElementById("name").value;
}
function mostrar(){
  // console.log(l) // esto no funciona ya que no es su ambito y es local de la otra funcion
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="crear()">Crear</button>
<button onclick="mostrar()">Mostrar</button>
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
<input id='name'>
```

Tienes mas información sobre los ámbitos [aqui](http://librosweb.es/libro/javascript/capitulo_4/ambito_de_las_variables.html)

Answer (score 2):

No te esta guardando la valor en la variable ya que "x", es una variable local de la función crear() , por lo cual no es accesible desde mostrar().
Una opción es declarar "var x" como variable global.
Saludos!

```html
var x;
function crear(){
  x = document.getElementById("name").value;
}
function mostrar(){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto se debe a que tienes dos funciones y la variable **x** esta fuera del contexto de la función **mostrar** podrias llamar al contenido directamente en la función mostrar.

```
function mostrar(){
var x = document.getElementById("name").value;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es por que la variable 'x' no existe en la funcion mostrar, una solucion seria pasarlo por parametro, o que la variable 'x' sea global.

```js
function crear() {
  var x = document.getElementById("name").value;
  mostrar(x)
}

function mostrar(x) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name">

<button onclick="crear()">Crear</button>
<button onclick="mostrar()">Mostrar</button>
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
```